# How to generate User specific feeds?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, facebook-like

I have 2 tables -  Pages and Feeds. 
Each feed belong to a specific page.
The user follows the interested page.

My requirement is to provide feeds for the user from the pages he has followed in a random way. That is, if page1 has 5 feeds & page2 has 5 feeds, I would like display these 10 feeds in a random way so that user doesn't get bored with feed from single page.

PS:

1. Pages will contain feeds more than 5.
2. If user likes, 3 or more pages, The feeds has to be fetched accordingly.
3. Each time max 10 feeds are fetched(for optimization) so I need to know how to iterate from the previous point.

Backend:

1. Google App Engine
2. Python Environment
3. Google Data store

Is there any way to achieve this?